# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__employee__super___21A0F6C4' on table 'employee' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
--First I created this table
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40),
    birth_day DATE,
    sex VARCHAR(1),
    salary INT,
    super_id INT,
    branch_id INT
);

--Then this
CREATE TABLE branch 
(
    branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    branch_name VARCHAR(40),
    mgr_id INT,
    mgr_start_date DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) 
        ON DELETE SET NULL
);

--Then I altered the table employee
ALTER TABLE employee
   ADD FOREIGN KEY(branch_id)
       REFERENCES branch(branch_id)
           ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE employee
    ADD FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id)
        REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
            ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

But I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__employee__super___21A0F6C4' on table 'employee' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: And yes it does show that error, because thats the situation, what are you wanting assistance with?

Comment: How do I use 'ON DELETE SET NULL' while altering the employee table?

Comment: You can't, because you are creating a reference loop, as the error says, so you want branch to link to employee and on delete set null, and have the same in the reverse direction, which creates a loop, which is not allowed.

Comment: This is allowed in mysql server but not is mssql server. Can you suggest any alternatives.

Comment: So how do I add foreign keys to the employee table while also making them null if they are deleted?

Comment: You should tag SQL Server! To have your thing work both ways you may need a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Circular declarative integrity references between two tables induce resonance phenomena due to recursion.

Table A checks Table B that checks Table A... ad infinitum ! The ISO SQL Standard rejects such a circulor ref except if the RDBMS have the feature to use deferred constraints... That induce more complicated coding strategies. SQL Server does not accept  deferred constraints, nor Circular integrity references.

The fact that MySQL allows such a thing is not a reference as this pseudo RDBMS is buggy and often gives random results.

However, you can still simulate such a constraint through a procedural integrity check. In this case you have to code a set of triggers...